# Добавление атрибутов к тегам Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify, schema.org, микроразметка

Как добавить свои атрибуты к тегам [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com). Хочу прикрутить [Schema.org](https://schema.org/TechArticle) к страницам.

Пример компонента:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-layout row wrap >
            <v-flex xs12>
                <h1 class="content-title display-1">{{ post.title }}</h1>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12>
                <div class="content-body" v-html="getMarkdown(post.text)"></div>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так же как и к любому другому тэгу.
[image: code]
[image: Браузер]

Comment: Ой, а можете, пожалуйста, сделать код текстом

Comment: В данном ответе использовались скриншоты в целях показать что к любому UI компоненту vuetify вы можете добавлять любые атрибуты как и к элементам стандартного HTML. Сам код на изображениях является всего лишь примером то что вы пишите в коде и то что вы потом увидите в браузере.